# Listing AWS instances from multiple accounts in a single call

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

The setup I've got:

- AWS Account A
- AWS Account B
- AWS EC2 Instance C running in Account A
- AWS EC2 Instance D running in Account B
- Account B has a policy for describing instances and this policy is trusted to Account A.
- Account A has a role with Account B's describing instances policy, along with a policy allowing it to describe its own instances.
- EC2 Instance C (on Account A) is running under this role which allows access to describe instances in both accounts.

When I run `aws ec2 describe-instances` on Instance C, only Instance C is returned, rather than both C and D. Some reading I've done suggests I can explicitly assume the role for Account B on Instance C, but then I'll *only* get the Account B instances, not Account A. Is it possible to have a single call return both sets of instances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The API call will only return a list of instances **for the AWS Account associated with the credentials being used**, and only for the Region to which the command was issued.

This is pretty much the case for all AWS API calls. They are made to **one account and one region only**. (Exceptions are global services such as IAM, Route 53 and CloudFront, plus the ability for Amazon S3 to return a list of buckets in all regions.)